# tabfigures and scrreprt: tabular figures in ToC

Tags: koma-script, minionpro

A MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{universalis}

%\usepackage[toc]{tabfigures}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{73}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\section{First section}
\clearpage
\section{Second section}
\clearpage
\section{Third section}

\chapter{This is the second chapter}
Blabla.

\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image]

I would like to have the proportional figures provided by MinionPro (chapter/section numbers as well as page numbers) vertically aligned: They should be typeset in tabular figures. The `tabfigures` package intends to achieve this. Uncommenting the line containing `\usepackage[toc]{tabfigures}` above will give:

[image]

While the section figures are now properly aligned, `tabfigures` tries to patch the figures associated with chapters (which are typeset using the sans-serif font when using the `scrreprt` class) as well. The `pdflatex` log says:

```
(C:\Users\mail\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/universalis\t1universalisad
fstd-lf.fd) (mwe.toc
No file T1UniversalisADFStd-TLF.fd.
No file T1UniversalisADFStdx.fd.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/UniversalisADFStd/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 1.
```

Here is what I get when using `\documentclass{book}` along with `\usepackage[toc]{tabfigures}`:

[image]

Looking good. `book` uses the roman font for displaying chapter titles. Using `\documentclass{scrreprt}` with `\usepackage[toc]{tabfigures}` and `\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\rmfamily}` is a workaround where ToC chapter entries will be typeset in MinionPro while leaving chapter headings in the actual document in sans-serif letters. However, I would like to stick to the default style of `scrreprt` with chapters being sans-serif within the ToC AND the document itself. Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I got into touch with the author of `tabfigures`, Michael Ummels. He found out what's causing the issue here and agreed that I may share the solution with you. Hope that I'm reciting this in an accurate way:

Universalis defines`-LF` fonts (lining figures), but none of type `-TLF` (tabular lining figures). The package `fontaxes` (which tabfigures is based upon) will not find the proper font to display the tabular lining figures. The author proposed to use the following workaround:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{universalis}

\usepackage[toc]{tabfigures}

% fix missing tabular lining figures for Universalis
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{UniversalisADFStd}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{UniversalisADFStd}{m}{n}{
      <-> ssub * UniversalisADFStd-LF/m/n
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{UniversalisADFStd}{b}{n}{
      <-> ssub * UniversalisADFStd-LF/b/n
}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{73}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\section{First section}
\clearpage
\section{Second section}
\clearpage
\section{Third section}

\chapter{This is the second chapter}
Blabla.

\end{document}
```

Will produce:

[image]

One may fix related `Font shape 'T1/UniversalisADFStd/x/y' undefined` messages analogously. Also, Michael Ummels said that he was going to provide an updated version of `fontaxes` which should fix the underlying issue. Given that 1.0e was uploaded on 21 July, I guess that this might have already happened!